# Green screen/freeze during videos/gifs

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, screen, video, system-freeze

Since a few days, I've some troubles when I watch gifs/videos on my nexus 4.
The phone freeze at the beginning of the video, then the screen turn green, and during 4/5 minutes I can't do anything. I must wait until the application crash.

Anyone have an idea ?
I'm using Android 5.0

Thanks !

Comment: What app are you using for watching GIF/video?

Comment: I've noticed the problem using 9Gag, Chrome and Snapchat

Comment: Same here, haven't found a solution yet